# Using Javascript to extract system time to display countdown

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use javascript in html to extract system time from browser and display a countdown to a future date, but its just not working. I have the code to show, would appreciate if someone could help me out with what I am doing wrong here.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chapter 9-1 Midwest Bridal Expo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--Hide from old browsers
        function countDown() {
            var today = new Date()
            var dayofweek = today.toLocaleString()
            dayLocate = dayofweek.indexOf(" ")
            weekDay = dayofweek.substring(0, dayLocate)
            newDay = dayofweek.substring(dayLocate)
            dateLocate = newDay.indexOf(",")
            monthDate = newDay.substring(0, dateLocate + 1)
            yearLocate = dayofweek.indexOf("2014")
            year = dayofweek.substr(yearLocate, 4)

            var bridalExpo = new Date("February 12, 2014")
            var daysToGo = bridalExpo.getTime() - today.getTime()
            var daysToBridalExpo = Math.ceil(daysToGo / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))

            displayCountDown.innerHTML = "<p style='font-size:12pt; font-family:Helvetica;'>Today is " + weekDay + " " + monthDate + " " + year + ". We have " + daysToBridalExpo + " days until the Midwest Bridal Expo.</p>"
        }

        function scrollColor() {
            styleObject = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style
            styleObject.scrollbarFaceColor = "#ffde5b"
            styleObject.scrollbarTrackColor = "ffba00"
        }

        function loadInfo(myForm) {
            var menuSelect = myForm.Menu.selectedIndex
            var menuUrl = myForm.Menu.options[menuSelect].value + ".html"
            window.location = menuUrl
        }

        function copyRight() {
            var lastModDate = document.lastModified
            var lastModDate = lastModDate.substring(0, 10)
            displayCopyright.innerHTML = "<p style='font-size:12pt; font-family:Helvetica;'>Today is " + weekDay + " " + monthDate + " " + year + ". We have " + daysToBridalExpo + " days until the Midwest Bridal Expo.</p>"
        }
        //-->
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .center {
            text-align:center;
        }
        img {
            border:0px;
        }
        .left-align {
            width: 50%;
            left: 0;
        }
        .right-align {
            width: 50%;
            right: 0;
            text-align: right;
        }
        table {
            width: 80%;
            margin-right: 10%;
            margin-left: 10%;
        }
        td {
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onLoad="scrollColor(); countDown(); copyRight()">
    <div class="center">
        <p>
            <img src="chapter9-1banner.jpg" width="747" height="160" alt="Bridal Expo Banner">
        </p>
        <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold;">Midwest Bridal Expo</p>
        <img src="hrimg-wedding-burgundy.jpg" width="750" height="5" alt="hr">
        <div id="displayCountDown"></div>
        <img src="hrimg-wedding-burgundy.jpg" width="750" height="5" alt="horizonal rule">
    </div>
    <table class="centerTable">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <p style="font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14pt">Planning your summer or fall wedding</p>
                <p style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:12pt">The Midwest Bridal Expo opens in Michigan on February 12, 2014 at the Ford Convention Center. This Expo is for all couples planning to get married in the next year, with an emphasis on those planning a summer or fall wedding. We have assembled a group of experts from all areas of wedding planning to help you plan your perfect day.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <p style="font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14pt">What awaits you</p>
                <p style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:12pt">Our full day of events include seminars with keynote speakers, one-on-one sessions with professional wedding planners, and various vendors from bakers to photographers with experience at all levels of wedding planning. You will be able to sample wedding cakes, see photo galleries by acclaimed photographers, and meet with hall rental representatives. And do not forget to discuss whether you want a live band or a DJ to provide music at that all-important reception.</p>
                <p style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:12pt">When you arrive, be sure to register for the grand prize drawing. Many of the individual vendors will also have raffles at their booths for special prizes, like free wedding cakes, free limo service, or free bouquets for the bride.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="right-align">
                <img src="393px-Wedding_cake_with_pillar_supports,_2009.jpg" width="197" height="300" alt="" style="background-color: #7f1100">
            </td>
            <td class="left-align">
                <img src="Western_wedding_dress_in_Taiwan.jpg" width="226" height="300" alt="" style="background-color: #7f1100">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <form id="announceMenu">
                    <p style="font-weight:bolder">For more information about the Expo:
                        <select name="Menu" onChange="loadInfo(this.form)">
                            <option>Select a topic</option>
                            <option value="chapter09vendor">Vendor List</option>
                            <option value="chapter09schedule">Schedule</option>
                            <option value="chapter09tips">Wedding Tips</option>
                        </select>
                    </p>
                </form>
            </td>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <p style="font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14pt">Ticket Information: <span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size: 10pt">For ticket reservations </span><span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:8pt">call 555-555-5555 x2205. Early bird ticket holders get a 10% discount..</span>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <p></p>
    <div id="displayCopyright"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should not say "It's not working" instead you should tell exactly what it is doing that you consider as "not working". What is wrong and what do you expect instead?

Comment: this is the error im getting in firebug ReferenceError: daysToBridalExpo is not defined
 

...ont-family:Helvetica;'>Today is "+weekDay+" "+monthDate+" "+year+". We have "+da...

chapter9-1.html (line 41)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `daysToBridalExpo` is declared in scope of `countDown` so you can't use it  `copyRight()` function, try to declare it before `countDown` and remove `var` when assigning value.

```
var daysToBridalExpo;
function countDown() {
...
  daysToBridalExpo = Math.ceil(daysToGo / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of jQuery plugins that do this.  The first Google result is this one: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html but there are others as well.  You should be able to find one to do pretty much any kind of countdown you could want and if you need some custom logic, you should be able to add that in as well.

Comment: I need to be able to do this with js because this is a class project